# To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.4` エラーを解決したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

#### 前提・実現したいこと

railsにてWheneverを使ってRakeタスクを定期実行をしたいです
その際に、logを確認しますと下記のようなエラーが発生します。
2日以上こちらが解決できない状態です。
みなさまのお知恵をお借りしたいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.4`
```

#### 試したこと

`gem install bundler:2.1.4`が反映されていないと思い、以下の記事を参考にして順に実行

[Railsアプリ開発で陥りがちなエラーとその対策集](https://qiita.com/kodai_0122/items/c4c13e89dd5c4cba1f32#%E5%AF%BE%E5%87%A6%E6%B3%95)

(1) Gemfile.lockを削除

```
$ rm Gemfile.lock
```

(2) バージョン2.1.4のbundlerをインストール

```
$ gem install bundler -v 2.1.4
```

(3) (2)のbundlerを用いて再度gemを入れ直す

```
$ bundler _2.1.4_ install
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/355615) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 参照記事の該当部分には「なので、`~/.bash_profile`の内容をもう一度読み込ませてみます。... この状態で、また先ほどのエラーと同じ手順を踏めばOKです。」とありますが、`(1)`の前にそれを行っているのでしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージと書かれていますが、その内容はbundlerをアップデートする方法の説明です。
それより前に、"Error"を含むメッセージが出ているのではないですか？　（Errorという語が含まれていないエラーメッセージというのは、見かけません）